# Can I have a RAID 1 pair with different capacity disks?

Tags: raid1

I have the following server configuration;

Intel Pentium 3.0 HT processor, 3 GB RAM, Intel Entry Server Board SE7230 NH1-E, 2 x 80 GB HDD (RAID-1)

I think one HDD has crashed so I want to replace it with a new HDD. Is this possible and can I migrate bad HDD to 250/320 GB or does it requires the same HDD capacity ?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Laxmilal

Answer (score 4):

It will work, but from what I remember you will only be able to use as much capacity as the smallest HDD on the RAID array.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly standard Intel ICH7-based SATA RAID 0/1 board so I strongly suspect it will just work if you replace the 80 with a larger disk.

That said I'm sure you'll be backing up your system before doing this work so even if it doesn't work you'll be able to create as new larger R1 array and restore from backup right.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks, Will update my setup on this weekend.